# SSRS how to pass the last value of a matrix row to the YTD value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Here is an image of my test report, what I want to do is show the last value of the row “annualized admissions per 1000” in the YTD column(painted in yellow) For example in my report the last value that I have is November(14.0) this is the value that I want to show in YTD . If my last value was September (15.0) that’s the value I want to show in YTD

The expression that im using to get values for months are:

> =IIF(Lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!SUMMEMBERSHIP.Value, "MembershipSum")=0,0,((Sum(Fields!ADMISSION.Value) * 12000) / IIf(Lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!SUMMEMBERSHIP.Value, "MembershipSum")=0,1,Lookup(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!SUMMEMBERSHIP.Value, "MembershipSum"))))

[image]

Comment: Is this matrix grouped by row and column or no groups?

Comment: Its grouped by columns. Im using the column of months.